# How to implement Haptic/3D Touch in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, 3dtouch

How can I detect the force of a touch gesture in SwiftUI?

I can already do the following:

```swift
    view.onTapGesture { ... }
```

But how do I fire a different closure based on touch force, or wrap a UIKit view to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.contextMenu` to display a list of actions for a specific element.

```
Text("Press hard or hold for context menu")
.contextMenu
{
    Button(action: { print("Action 1 triggered") }, label:
    {
        Text("Action 1")
    })
    
    Button(action: { print("action 2 triggered") }, label:
    {
        Text("Action 2")
    })
}
```