# How to implement a 3D touch preview in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, 3dtouch

how is it possible to implement a long press or 3D touch preview like the google news example or the one from instagram?
When tapped in the preview, it should be forwarded to the destination"page.

[image: 3D touch to open preview]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement Haptic/3D Touch in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62684696/how-to-implement-haptic-3d-touch-in-swiftui)

Comment: Thanks but no, i want more content in the long-press preview, not just text.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804307/swiftui-custom-view-for-context-menu/70804869#70804869

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Custom View For Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804307/swiftui-custom-view-for-context-menu)